# Removing the duplicate id in jstl

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I am using jstl. In my page there is a loop which creates div's with different ids but i have seen there are some of the div( after loop completion) having the same id which(div) i want to remove or say want to prevent them to be created. I want to achieve it inside the loop itself through jstl. Please help.

Please find the code segment-

```
<c:forEach var="menuType" items="${menuTypes}" begin="0" varStatus="mCount">
                <c:set var="mcnt" value="${mCount.count}"></c:set>
                    <div class="window" id="window${mcnt}"  onmouseout="hideBub('${mcnt}');" style="top:${mcnt*200}px">
                        <div id="inner-cont${mcnt}" class="inner-cont" align="center" onmouseover="showBubble('${mcnt}');">
                            ${menuType.functionName}(<span id="totRecord"></span>)
                            <div class="bubble" id="bubble${mcnt}" style="margin-left:50px;" onmouseout="hideBub('${mcnt}');">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>[+]&nbsp;Add New
                                    </span>
                                </a> 
                                <hr>
                                <div class="box">
                                    <div class="box-content">
                                        <table width="100%" class="hovertable">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr><td></td></tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="dispRec${mcnt}" class="dispRec"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div align="center" class="btnContainer" style="width:90px;">
                            <span class="linkButton"><a href="#" style="color:white;text-decoration: none;">View</a></span>
                            <span class="linkButton"><a href="#" style="color:white;text-decoration: none;">Edit</a></span>
                            <span class="linkButton"><a href="#" style="color:white;text-decoration: none;">Delete</a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div align="center" class="btnContainer" style="width:47px;float: right">
                            <span class="linkButton" style="display: inline-block;padding: 1px;margin-right: 2px">
                                <a href="#" style="color:white;text-decoration: none;">Analysis</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is that the only loop - or is there an outer loop that isn't shown? Can you update your post with an example of the resulting HTML containing divs with duplicate ids?

Comment: Yes this is the only loop.

Comment: Which div are you seeing with duplicate ids?

Comment: Instead of `${mCount.count}` use `${mCount.index}`.